# How do i make react re-render on scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

My code is meant to activate a process when it scrolls passed a point.

Everything works, but the use effect hook does not activate unless I have state change to cause a re-render. How can I change this so inactivates? When I just had a conditional internal change of the state it was both lag prone and caused a problem with changing to another page.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let myRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect( () => {

    if (window.pageYOffset > myRef.current.offsetTop)
    { console.log("hello friend")
    }
    })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(myRef.current.offsetTop);
        }}
      >
        {" "}
        test
      </button>
      <br />

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div ref={myRef}>
        <h1> hi, this is a test</h1>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
 <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is a code pen with my exact problem.
https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-silence-8f07c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your demo does nothing with scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you set `YoffSet` in state like so:

`const [yOffSet, setYoffSet] = useState('')`

then in `useEffect` add a event listener:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll",() => {
      if(window.pageYoffSet > chooseAValue) {
        setYoffSet(//whateverValueYouWant)
      }
  }, []);
```

then you are setting state and this will trigger a re-render

Comment: thankyou, the "window.addEventListener" bit I was missing. much appreciated :)